# Multiple Recyclerview issues within scroll view adding unnecessary space

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scrollview

I am using the two recyclerview within scrollview. Below is my xml code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/movieTitleView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:background="#40C4FF">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/movie_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/movieSynopsisView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/movieTitleView">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/movieImg"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:src="@drawable/sample" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReleaseDate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movieImg"
                android:text="releasedate"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/vote"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvReleaseDate"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movieImg"
                android:text="voteavera"
                android:textSize="14sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnFavourite"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="53dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/vote"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movieImg"
                android:text="@string/btn_favourite" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvSynopsis"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/movieImg"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="synopsis"
                android:textSize="13sp" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/movieDivider"
                android:layout_width="350dp"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/tvSynopsis"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                android:background="#000000" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvTrailer"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/movieDivider" />


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvReview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_below="@id/rvTrailer"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

`

First recyclerview created and i can able to scroll. But with second recycleview
there is an extra space added. I am not adding any padding.Second recycleview is created below the screen ie, when the page loads. First recycle view occupies full screen.

Do I miss anything ?

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace second RecyclerView's android:layout_height="match_parent" attribute to  android:layout_height="wrap_content" as follows:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvReview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/rvTrailer" />
```

Comment: I  changed the height to wrap_content.  Still issue not resolved. Iam using recycler view compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'